# How to get values in multiple edited cells of DataGridView for updating the database

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DGV that looks like this:

[image: Example DGV for editing multiple cells]

Each row in the DGV is a record in a database table.

I need to allow the user to edit any cell(s) they wish and then on a button click update the database with the new values. (There is a hidden column that holds the record's database table ID.)

I know I can grab the old value of a cell by reading it on the CellEnter event, then getting the new value on CellLeave (at least that's the way I know how to do it), but that's just for one cell. How do I accomplish that for multiple cells at once? One thought I had was to create a multidimensional array to store the row and column indexes and the new and old values for each edited cell and then read through the array to update the database. But I'm not sure that's the best way to go about this.

Another option I thought of was iterating through every cell in the DGV, but doing that would I be able to get both the old and new values in a cell that was edited by the user?

Answer (score 0):

It is easier than you think.
There is no need to iterate over the DGV. If it is bound to a **datatable** (or dataset), just let the user enter and change data in the grid, and the datatable will update itself.

> I know I can grab the old value of a cell by reading it on the
>   CellEnter event, then getting the new value on CellLeave

Unnecessary. Using the datatable you can access the original value and the new value of a cell, and compare them. See [`datarowversion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowversion?view=netframework-4.8%20datarowstate). But if you just want to tell which rows were modified, you could simply use the [`datarowstate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowstate?view=netframework-4.8) function.

Then, to update the data on the backend DB, you could use a [`SqlDataAdapter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?view=netframework-4.8).
You might need some constraints on the datatable and on the grid for validation purposes (for example if some cells may not be empty). But overall, there is almost no need to access the DGV directly. Instead, you work with the datasource.